# cat files in specific order based on number in filename

Tags: files, cat, text-formatting

I have files named `file.88_0.pdb`, `file.88_1.pdb`, `...`, `file.88_100.pdb`. I want to `cat` them so that `file.88_1.pdb` gets pasted after `file.88_0.pdb`, `file.88_2.pdb` after `file.88_1.pdb`, and so on. If I do `cat file.88_*.pdb > all.pdb`, the files are put together in the following order: `0 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20...`, etc. How do I put them together so that the order is `0 1 2 3 4 5 6...`?

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in our new [bioinformatics.se] site if you're working in the field.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`brace expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

```
cat file.88_{0..100}.pdb >>bigfile.pdb
```

To ignoring printing the error messages for non-existent files use:

```
cat file.88_{0..100}.pdb >>bigfile.pdb 2>/dev/null
```

In the `zsh` shell also you have the `(n)` globbing qualifier to request a *numerical* sorting (as opposed to the default of *alphabetical*) for globs:

```
cat file.88_*.pdb(n) >>bigfile.pdb 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 9):

In shell w/o brace expansion, if you file names don't contain whitespace, quotes nor backslashes, you can use `ls` (assuming the GNU implementation) + `xargs`:

```
ls -v file.88_*.pdb | xargs cat > all.pdb
```

`ls` will sort files in numeric order:

`-v`     natural sort of (version) numbers within text.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat $(for((i=0;i<101;i++)); do echo -n "file.88_${i}.pdb "; done)
```

or, regarding the comment of Jesse_b:

```
cat $(for((i=0;i<101;i++)); do test -f "file.88_${i}.pdb" && echo -n "file.88_${i}.pdb "; done)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
filedir="/path/to/files"
output="/path/to/all.pdb"
for file in $(find $filedir -type f -name "file.88_*" | sort -t "_" -k2 -n); do
    cat $file >> $output
done
```

This was able to `sort` the files on by the (`-k2`) second field using `_` as a separator.  Here you have to use `>>` otherwise each new file will overwrite the last.

Comment: I still get the wrong order: `0 1 10 11 12...`

Comment: what os are you running? if you do `sort --version` what do you get?  And you have the `-n` in the sort command right?

Comment: OSX El Capitan, `sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93`

Comment: I have GNU 8.22 but I don't think `-n` is that new.  If you just run:  `find ./ -type f -name "file.88_*" | sort -t "_" -k2 -n`  in that directory it should print out a list in the correct order if not we may have to tweak the sort command?

Comment: Ok the sort command itself works.

Comment: are you deleting your output file in between runs? :p

Comment: Yes, I do delete it.

Comment: The other two answers are much better anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying! The `/dev/null` addition to the other answer was much needed!

Comment: [Useless use of command substitution](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks). Use something like `find ... | sort ... | xargs cat >> $output` instead.